# fragments overlap each other by pressing the back

Tags: android

I have akivity with one button and frame:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button replaceBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment);
        replaceBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment:
                Fragment fragment1 = new Frag1();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame, fragment1);
                **fTrans.addToBackStack(null);**
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

button is pressed, etc. I create a fragment:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment  implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, null);
        Button replaceBtn2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment2);
        replaceBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment2:
                Frag2 fragment2 = new Frag2();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame,fragment2);
                **fTrans.addToBackStack(null);**
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

it also has a button which when pressed I create fragment2:

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, null);
        Button replaceBtn3 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.replaceFragment3);
        replaceBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.replaceFragment3:
                Frag3 fragment3 = new Frag3();
                FragmentTransaction fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fTrans.replace(R.id.contentFrame,fragment3);
                **//do not add backstack**
                fTrans.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

fragment2 also creates a new fragment3:

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3, null);
        return v;
    }
}
```

then later when I press the "back" button on the screen will appear the fragments in reverse order. but I want to when I'm in fragmente3 when you press the "back" appears immediately fragment1.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

that is because you don't added the fragment2 to backstack. The fragment wont be pop back or disappear when  they excluded from backstack. backstack runs exactly as activity back stack or any other stack container works.

to explain better:

added first fragment to stack

1. [stack]  topElement Fragment1 (is showing)
2. added 2nd but did not add to the stack [stack]  topElement
   Fragment1(is not showing)
3. added 3rd fragment to stack [stack]  topElement Fragment3(is
   showing)

now if you pop it will return in this order : 3rd,1st and nothing more.

**EDIT**

in this case you can simply override the onBackPressed() like this to achieve the behaviour you want:

onBackPressed(){

//default back pressed behaviour 
if(mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()==0)//you can set it ==1 if you wish to close
   finish();

mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}

Comment: I knew it. I realize the problem? I need to be on the fragment 3 by clicking back I got into fragment1

Comment: can you tell exactly what order you want to get?
open: 1,2,3
close: 3,2,1  ?

Comment: fragment1 - entry point. in it I can create fragment2 and in fragmente2 can create fragment3 and so on. but when I click the back button I have to get out in the fragment1.open 1,2,3,4,5...n close 1

Comment: you mean  open 1,2,3,4,5..n close: only 1st? or you mean close in exact order you open    ?

Comment: I loaded fragment1. out of it I can open other fragments. there may be many. in a different order. but one of the other offers. and when I click the back button, I want to get always fragment1. even though many have been discovered fragments after him.

Comment: for example - 1,2,3,4,5. then if I press Back fragment5 I get to fragment1.
if during fragmente4 I press back, I also get to fragment1.